# How to aggregate factor variable?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
ID    month    country   count    style
1     2012-02  UK        3        high
1     2012-02  US        10       high
1     2012-02  FR        5        high
etc
```

Now, I want to aggregate the values over the `ID` and `country` variable and, therefore, I use:

```
aggregated_data = setDT(subset)[, .(Country = list(Country), ID = min(ID), 
count = sum(count), by = list(Model, Month)][]
```

To get

```
ID    month    country     count    
1     2012-02  UK, US, FR   18      
etc
```

However, since my `style` variable is a factor I do not know how I can incorporate this in the aggregated table. The values of the factor variable is always the same for one `ID`, so I only need to print the first value of the `style` variable for the `style` variable in the aggregated table. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your expected output is ambiguous, what exactly is counted in your resulting table? BTW, have you ever concerned about how to [properly provide data on Stack Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). You could do this in a better way than you've done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `unique`, e.g.

```
df <- setDT(df)
df[, .(country = toString(country), count = sum(count), style = unique(style)), by = list(ID, month)]
#   ID   month    country count style
#1:  1 2012-02 UK, US, FR    18  high
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID, month) %>%
    summarise(
        country = toString(country),
        count = sum(count),
        style = unique(style))
## A tibble: 1 x 5
## Groups:   ID [?]
#     ID month   country    count style
#  <int> <fct>   <chr>      <int> <fct>
#1     1 2012-02 UK, US, FR    18 high
```

Both methods assume that `style` is always the same per `ID` and `month`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ID    month    country   count    style
1     2012-02  UK        3        high
1     2012-02  US        10       high
1     2012-02  FR        5        high", header = T)
```